# How to deserialize JSON without static key/property names

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

Hello I have problem with deserializing IRestResponse.Content JSON response.

```
{
"49": 
    {
        "9345": "2018-10-11", 
        "106": null, 
        "107": "4222238842", 
        "108": "CompanyName", 
        "8210": "2018-11-11/1", 
        "110": "00-300", 
        "109": "Street", 
        "112": "Country", 
        "18418": null, 
        "18420": "S\u0141ON", 
        "18422": "OtherString", 
        "9338": null, 
        "111": "City"
    }
}
```

I have tried some webpage's or built in VisualStudio converter but It gives my something like this.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public _49 _49 { get; set; }
}

public class _49
{
    public string _9345 { get; set; }
    public object _106 { get; set; }
    public string _107 { get; set; }
    public string _108 { get; set; }
    public string _8210 { get; set; }
    public string _110 { get; set; }
    public string _109 { get; set; }
    public string _112 { get; set; }
    public object _18418 { get; set; }
    public string _18420 { get; set; }
    public string _18422 { get; set; }
    public object _9338 { get; set; }
    public string _111 { get; set; }
}
```

This look's ok but In my case those JSON files have dynamic property names and can have another "int" values. Also the nested content inside "49" can have less or more values.
I am especially interested in gathering "49" << this value to variable.

I also have tried something like this, but doesn't work either:

```
public class DeserializeJsonContent
{
   public Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>> values { get; set; }
}
```

Simplified code sample

```
    public List<T> JSONDeserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) where T : new()
    {
        var responseData = client.Deserialize<List<T>>(response);
        var ListDeserializedData = responseData.Data.ToList<T>();
        return ListDeserializedData;
    }
```

....

```
var response = rest.client.Execute(request);
if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    var obj = rest.JSONDeserialize<DeserializeJsonContent>(response);
}
```

obj has count 1 but vals = null

**Edit after Solve:**
I still have no idea why my deserialized class doesn't work in this case (I am using it in many other json deserialization response's)
Thanks to xdtTransform answer I have tried and all of those worked

```
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<object, object>>>(response.Content);
var obj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(response.Content);
var obj4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>(response.Content);
var obj5 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, Dictionary<string, string>>>(response.Content);
var obj6 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>>(response.Content);
var obj7 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, Dictionary<int, object>>>(response.Content);
```

Then just

```
var value = obj2.First().Key;
```

Comment: The dictionary approach is correct. How are you actually using it?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your `Dictionary` approach.

Comment: @cricket_007 i changed nested dictionary to string,object but still doesn't work, also added some code example

Comment: You don't need a separate class. Replace DeserializeJsonContent with just a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), You can directly deserialize to `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>` like :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>(input);
```

If you need it to be in your custom type, you should declare this type like :

```
public class WrapperType : Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>{}
```

Then the Deserialisation stay the same:

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WrapperType>(input);
```

[Updated demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ol8u6L)

Comment: Thanks! With 1st code example I solved my problem, also edited question on the bottom. Gonna try with WrapperType now :) Have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Please deserialize response content

```
string data = response.Content;

var responseData = client.Deserialize<List<T>>(data);
```